# Facebook Javascript SDK:Create Album in page Give error 283

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to made facebook application "website platform using default.aspx"
this application enable user for creating albums and upload photos to specific facebook page

in script 
i'am using my app accesstoken

and for creating album function

function CreateAlbum() {

var AlbumName = document.getElementById("AlbumName").value;

```
            var message = document.getElementById("descriptionAlbum").value;
            var pageaccess_token = "";
            FB.api('/**PageID**?fields=access_token', function (response) {

                pageaccess_token = response.access_token;
                console.log(pageaccess_token);
                FB.api('/**Pageid**/albums?access_token=' + pageaccess_token, 'POST',
                    {
                        name: AlbumName,
                        message: message
                    }, function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                   document.getElementById('albums').value =response.id;

                    });
            });



        }
```

and in body i'm using

fb:login-button

scope="public_profile,email,user_photos,friends_photos,user_photo_video_tags,friends_photo_video_tags,publish_actions,manage_pages,read_stream,publish_stream"

this was work but now it give me error in firebug

(#283) Requires extended permission: manage_pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am facing the same issue 
Response code: 403 (#283) Requires extended permission: manage_pages

I found [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/april-29-2015-facebook-errors-283-and-200)

Facebook moves EVERYBODY to the API 2.3 on April 30, 2015. If you got one of those errors you were on API 1.0.

neither re-authorization of the app or creating the app again works for me